# How to substitute an equation in python?

Tags: python, sympy

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, sin, sqrt

x = symbols('x')
D = symbols('d')
C = symbols('c')
eq1 = 2*sin(x)+sqrt(1-sin^2(x))+D*sin(x/2)-sin(2*x)-1-C

sol = solve(eq1)
print(sol)
```

Actually in the equation eq1=0. And I was trying to find a function for x which I couldn't find by mathematics. So I was thinking if it is possible in Python. My friend was saying that we actually deal with numbers in Python so he said it would be good if he can get some value of x. In that equation C and D is constant. He was saying that they are height. So we can consider that C,D=1 to 1000 (we can choose whatever we wish). Is there really possible way to substitute that function to find a value of x?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at sympy tutorial: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html

also Itk this should solve your problem: With @Oscar Benjamin advice:

```
from sympy import nsolve, sin, sqrt
from sympy.abc import x, C, D


eq1 = 2*sin(x)+sqrt(1-sin(x)**2)+C*sin(x/2)-sin(2*x)-1-D

sol = nsolve(eq1.subs({C: C_value, D: D_value}, x0)
print(sol)
```

x0 is the initialization of x, depending on the value of x0 you can end with different value of x verifying eq = 0.

Comment: This particular equation is very unlikely to have an explicit analytic solution so I would suggest choosing values for C and D and using nsolve.

Comment: True I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fsolve` to numerically solve the non-linear equation. The `subs` attribute of a sympy expression can be used to substitute a value to a variable.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, sin, sqrt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


x = symbols('x')
D = symbols('d')
C = symbols('c')

eq1 = 2*sin(x)+sqrt(1-(sin(x))**2)+D*sin(x/2)-sin(2*x)-1-C

values = {
    C: 500,
    D: 1000
}

eq1_in_x = eq1.subs(values)

def f(y):
    return float(eq1_in_x.subs(x,y[0]))

sol = fsolve(f,1) # Here, 1 is an initial guess.
print(sol)
```

Outout:

```
[1.04635456]
```

So, `1.04635456` is a value of `x` that satisfies the equation with `C` and `D` values being `500` and `1000`, respectively.

Comment: I don't think that's what I expected. Cause you said that "1" in fsolve is initial guess. But I don't think so, when I wrote 1000 instead of 1 I got some other result so I don't think that, it's something that I expected

Comment: I understood what that is, from documentation... x0 is actually f(x)=x0.. That's what it was representing.. We had wrote a function sin(x)+D+C+A=eq1 When working with it fsolve writes it like this fsolve(eq1,0) eq1=0...

Comment: @Unknown no, the second argument in fsolve is the initial guess. A nonlinear equation could have many solutions, and which solution fsolve converges to depends on which initial guess is passed. If you passed 1000 instead of 1 and if it gave you a value as the solution then that value would also satisfy the equation.

Comment: nsolve and fsolve is closely related. I still disagree with ur idea. And read others answer in this question. He explained it. And tomorrow I WILL just copy-paste the docwhenever I Will be on laptop

Comment: x0 : ndarray
        The starting estimate for the roots of ``func(x) = 0``. ~~~ minipack.py 60 no. line..

Comment: Yea, that's what i said. Initial guess is the starting estimate, from which the algorithm tries to converge to the actual solution.